# JSON.stringify(array)[0] gives [ instead of value at 0

Tags: jquery, angularjs, arrays

I have an array in the controller. I get the array from the controller in my html to display the values of array in a table. I use [datatable](http://datatables.net) from datatable.net for pagination. So I'm not using `ng-repeat` for the table. I store the input values from the html into the array which is used by datatable to create a table.

I have the array in the controller like this:

`newEmployeeArray = [{empid: 'value from input field', empname:'value from input field'}]`. I send this array to the jquery code that is used to add rows to the table using datatable's method to add rows dynamically.

In the html where I get the array from controller I get the array as an object. I use `JSON.parse(arrayFromController)`. But I dont think it's the right way.I want the access the array like `empid.value`. How to do this.

The jquery in html:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var t = $('#example').DataTable();

        $("#submitBtn").on('click',function(){
            var arrayFromController = (angular.element(document.getElementById('mainControllerID')).scope().getNewEmployeeArray());
t.row.add(arrayFromController);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(arrayFromController)[0]); //gives "["

        })
```

The controller which contains the array of values from input fields:

```
$scope.getNewEmployeeArray = function(){
    return $scope.newEmployeeArray
```

}

Comment: You should NOT mix Angular with jQuery.  It is absolutely bad practice.  Also, you should include your HTML so people can have a better understanding of what you are doing or trying to do in order to get some help.

Comment: You mean `JSON.stringify(arrayFromController[0])`, not `JSON.stringify(arrayFromController)[0]`. Also See @Rani's advice above

Comment: Your data may be looks like [{'id','1'}, .. etc]  so JSON.stringify(array)[0]   should be [ Try with arr[0]